# Share video to other app which show thumnail in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

when I share a youtube video via the youtube app from mobile to Whatsapp then it shows a thumbnail with the link is it possible to do it in a flutter as like that, in this video share range rover video on Whatsapp when I go to Whatsapp it looks like that, I want this in my flutter app any idea?

[image]

Comment: Get thumbnail https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068371/13701546 and format tile as you like. you can get other YT api here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails#resource if you need more data

Comment: @SimonSot i want that i am using share_plus package to share my video url to any app i share so when i share then this look like to show if my app is not download then if user click this video then it will go to playstore to download my app. this video is not coming from youtube but it came from restful api

Comment: it's called deeplinks, you should check docs here [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking)

Comment: @Ruchit i try or check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [firebase-dynamic-links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) for this.

[image: screenshot]

```
  void testingVideoLink() async {
    String uriPrefix = 'https://....page.link';
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
        uriPrefix: uriPrefix,
        link: Uri.parse('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_SB7h2kB6Eg'),
    );

    final ShortDynamicLink shortDynamicLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(parameters);
    Uri uri = shortDynamicLink.shortUrl;
    Share.share(uri.toString(), subject: '...');
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit what happens i am new in flutter so i dont understand easily

Comment: what is page.link why parse youtube link kingly explain @BloodLoss

Comment: link only show title with image and details for youtube i add my video link  which are on my server but the issue is it did not show as it did on youtube links